# I am trying to use spicy for image filters but it return an error

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use scipy for image filters

```
from scipy.ndimage import filters
```

It gives the error

> ImportError: No module named ndimage

Let me know how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Check file *\Lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage* if it exists.If it does,please download Scipy source code and compile it on your computer.